# Should we use Graph API or Office Management API for extracting DLP reports from the compliance portal?

Tags: powerbi, microsoft-graph-api, reporting, office365api, cloud-data-loss-prevention

Should we use Graph API or Office Management API for extracting DLP reports from the compliance portal ? Which is more sustainable ? Is there chances of getting any of them deprecated in future ? If you can provide me any Pros and Cons list of consuming them ?

We have extracted reports by using both the API's but we are confused which one should we use and the confusion is only because which one will be continued for long by Microsoft. Microsoft should keep supporting the solution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If your concerned about sustainability then you should use the Graph as that is the newest of the API and is Microsoft preference/recommended API for all application. While nothing has been announced if there is duplication in the API's I would expect the Office Management API to get depreciated in the future as has happened with other similar API (eg Office 365 Service Communications API).

Then only thing to watch is that Throttling maybe different between the two API as the Graph tends to be more restrictive the legacy endpoints. Also if your selling a product into different national clouds https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/deployments you should confirm that the endpoint is available in every cloud where you customers will be located.